# Do the rows of A form a basis for $R^5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis, invariant-subspace

Suppose $
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
    2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$  = 4.

**(1) $ \{(2, 1,0,1,0), (1,1,0,1,0), (1,1,0,2,1)\}$ is linearly independent.**

**(2) the rows form a basis for $r^5$**

**(3) $ \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}, 
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix},
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}\right\} $ is linearly independent.**

I think **(1), (2), (3) are correct,** but it is not possible for the sets in (1) and (3) to span $R^5$ since a minimum of 5 vectors is required, which is also the reason why (2) is correct? Please correct me if I am wrong thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. To check that something is a basis, you need to check that you have as many vectors as the dimension of the space _and_ you need to check that they are linearly independent. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition

Comment: Are you saying that (2) is correct because there are 5 rows? It is correct because the determinant is non-zero.

Comment: @Chrystomath The matrix is invertible, so the rows will form a basis for (2), but I am not sure about (1) and (3), I think that since all 5 vectors are linearly independent, then choosing 3 vectors out of the 5 will also be linearly independent, so (1) and (3) must be correct?

Comment: Yes. If a set of vectors is l.independent, then a proper subset of it will also be.

Comment: @H.Rittich In this case, both the sets in (1) and (2) are linearly independent, but have less than 5 vectors, which is the dimension of the $R^5$ space, so they will not span $R^5$? Would this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

To set things as clear as possible: don't forget that a basis is characterised as

- a *minimal* spanning set of the vector space,
- or a *maximal* linearly independent set of vectors.

When they ask whether a set of vectors is linearly independent, they do not mean it is a maximal linearly independent set. So there's no incompatibility.

As to question c), you just have to compute the determinant of the matrix, either by row reduction, or a combination of row reduction and expansion along a row or a column, when it has enough $0$s. I'll show a way to start:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0&1&0 \\ 2&1&0&1&0 \\1&2&0&1&1 \\1&1&0&2&1 \\0&0&2&0&2
\end{vmatrix}= 2\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}1&1&0&1&0 \\ 0&-1&0&-1&0 \\0&1&0&0&1 \\0&0&0&1&1 \\0&0&1&0&1
\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}-1&0&-1&0 \\1&0&0&1 \\0&0&1&1 \\0&\color{red}1&0&1
\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}-1&-1&0 \\1 &0&1 \\0 &1&1 
\end{vmatrix}\\[10ex]=\cdots$$